# Usage of static keyword in C++

Tags: c++, static-methods

I have a class exposing a static function in myclass.hpp

```
class MyClass {
public:
   static std::string dosome();
};
```

Well, in myclass.cpp what should I write:
this:

```
std::string MyClass::dosome() {
   ...
}
```

or this:

```
static std::string MyClass::dosome() {
   ...
}
```

I guess I should not repeat the static keyword... is it correct?

Comment: Don't repeat the static keyword but I'd be interested to find out why

Comment: @MattSmith: See my answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++ compiler will not allow this:

```
static std::string MyClass::dosome() {
   ...
}
```

since having `static` in a function definition means something completely different - `static` linkage (meaning the function can only be called from the same translation unit).

Having `static` in a member function declaration is enough.

Comment: Ah yeah you're right... it's like c... if it encounters a static function it means that it can only be called from the same... file or better, as you pointed out, translation unit. Thank you for your exaustive answer.

Answer (score 5):

Do not repeat the `static` keyword. To do so will result in an error.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**. The `static` keyword should not be used when defining a function body outside the class definition.